# Illegal transactions can also be mined on geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I used web3 to call the contract method (I initialized web3 with metamask, then metamask listens for the geth node).

I used to deploy the contract to ganache. When I used the illegal parameter to call the contract method (the contract method uses 'require' to determine if the parameter is correct), the result is revert, which is normal. But when I deployed the contract to the private network I built with geth and then called the method with illegal parameters, the result was no error, which is not normal.
And the transaction can be mined as a normal transaction[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal case the tx will be mined successfuly, but with status failed (which mean a revert in your contract code has happend and the state of your contract has not successfully changed),  this has nothing to do with the tranaction.

In you first case the transaction has not been sent to the blockchain, I think metamask test first your input on the contract code and state and if it successes, then it will send your transaction to the blockchain.

So i assume metamask couldnt do that with your  private network(geth) maybe you should change something in the config

However you can do that manually with web3js, instead of using .send(), you can use .call()
and if no error happen, then you run .send()

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send